# What to do in case of burst of requests on a site developed in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Express to build a site which is expected to have large amount of requests (around 900 at a single instance). What should I do to avoid the site to crash and the minimum hardware specs for the same.

Comment: You should test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some tests the other days. Nothing fancy, just to play around a little. If you do a lot of I/O, very heavy computations, etc. you should reconsider some aspects. The above example works the same in Express ... You can switch between the commented code and see for yourself how things works

```
// Linux command to generate the file
// dd if=/dev/zero of=myFile bs=1300000000 count=1

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 34242;
server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  // // Heady I/O
  // fs.readFile(__dirname + '/myFile', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  //   res.end('working hot');
  // });

  // No I/O
  res.end('working hot');
})
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started and listening on ${port}`);
  let count = 0

  // // Concomitant request
  // if No I/O on the server ->  fails if reqNumber is more than 400, Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:34242
  // if Heavy I/O on the server -> fails, Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:34242
  // const reqNumber = 300;
  // console.time('timeSpent');
  // for (let i = 0; i < reqNumber; i++) {
  //   http.get(`http://localhost:${port}`, (res) => {
  //     count++;
  //     if (count == reqNumber) {
  //       console.timeEnd('timeSpent');
  //     }
  //   })
  // }

  // Small interval between requests
  // if No I/O on the server -> it works well
  // if Heavy I/O on the server -> fails Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:34242
  let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    http.get(`http://localhost:${port}`, (res) => {
      console.log(count++)
    })
  }, 1)
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, 10500)
})
```